# What's the best CVS client for Windows?

Tags: windows, cvs, wincvs

We're currently using WinCVS but it's slow and has no merge dialog. I'm looking for something like Eclipse's Team Synchronize (so people can see what they'll get before they update).

What do you suggest? [TortoiseCVS](http://www.tortoisecvs.org/) with [WinMerge](http://winmerge.org/)?

Note: OSS preferred :)

Comment: For questions like these, I think sometimes the best place to look is http://alternativeto.net

Comment: A "Only CVS plugin enclosed" version of Eclipse?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

On windows, definitely using Tortoise CVS and WinMerge will meet your needs.  I also think it would be a good idea to learn how to do some operations with the command line too.

Comment: Dude, those answer are from 2 years ago... stuff change dont downvote people for that. The question is not for Win7 necessary.

Answer (score 15):

First: Strictly speaking, none of the tools quoted here so far are CVS **clients**. They're all "just" GUI frontends on top of the CVSNT commandline client (IIRC only SmartCvs uses a plain CVS client).

So, I'd be interested to hear what particular operations you think are slow in WinCvs. The real bottleneck is usually the CVS protocol itself and that will behave the same regardless of which GUI frontend you use.

Also, what exactly do you mean by "has no merge dialog"?
WinCvs integrates nicely with WinMerge (also as conflict editor).
And if you were talking about executing Merge operations you use the Update command which has a "Merge options" tab...

For previewing updates there are also several approaches in WinCvs: If you just want to see which files would get updated you can use the Query Update command (`cvs -n up`) or if you want the details you can simply Diff (using WinMerge) against `HEAD` (also works on multiple files and folders).

I've had both Tortoise and WinCvs installed for years but usually find that I do not use Tortoise except when I feel guilty about not getting what all the fuss is about... ;)

It's all a matter of taste I guess, especially whether you prefer an integrated solution that tries not to get in the way over a standalone app that forces you to make conscious decisions about your version control tasks.
WinCvs for me does all I want and more, but then I'm probably considered a power user and a heavily biased one at that as I used to be a cvsgui mailing list moderator and FAQ author and also wrote many of the stock macros.

Then again, there hasn't really been any active development on WinCvs for quuuuiiiite some time... :(

Comment: I loved WinCVS until I saw the Team Synchronize view in Eclipse. All of a sudden, I realized what WinCVS lacked.

Comment: I'll have a look at that - though, not being a Java developer, I doubt that I'll switch... ;)

Answer (score 13):

TortoiseCVS with WinMerge is my choice too for **CVS**.

Comment: As I mentioned before, please be aware that currently they no longer support Window Vista or 7. Any other option?

Comment: Dude, those answer are from 2 years ago... stuff change dont downvote people for that. The question is not for Win7 necessary.

Comment: @luiscolorado: Really? I've been using TortoiseCVS with WinMerge and Windows 7 for about a year now without any problems.

Comment: Just installed the latest version and I am unable to get it to function on Win 7.

Answer (score 13):

[SmartCVS](http://www.syntevo.com/smartcvs/index.html) is another good choice for CVS.

Answer (score 2):

I was also searching for this currently. I got my eye on WinCVS and I liked it. but for my java projects I prefer eclipse which fulfills all my needs..

edit.. my bad.. didnt see the date :(